reset_password function causing Internal Server Error
i work in django project and i have this function :
def reset_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        email = request.POST['email']

        try:
            # Check if the user exists
            user = RestPassword.objects.get(email=email)

            # Generate a unique reset token
            reset_token = str(uuid.uuid4())
            user.reset_token = reset_token
            user.save()

            # Send the reset password email
            subject = 'Password Reset'
            message = f'Please click the following link to reset your password: {settings.SITE_URL}/authentication/reset/{reset_token}/'
            from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
            recipient_list = [email]
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
            success_message = 'A password reset link has been sent to your email.'
            return render(request, "authentication/login.html", {'success_message': success_message})
        except RestPassword.DoesNotExist:
            error_message = 'No account found with the provided email.'
            return render(request, "authentication/reset_password.html", {'error_message': error_message})

    return render(request, "authentication/reset_password.html")```

and this the HTML fil
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Password Reset</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #f8f9fa;
    }
    
    .container {
      max-width: 400px;
      margin: 100px auto;
      padding: 30px;
      border: 1px solid #ced4da;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    
    .btn-reset {
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Password Reset</h2>
    <form id="resetPasswordForm" action="{% url 'reset_password' %}" method="POST">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required>
      </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-reset" onclick="return verificate_email()">Reset Password</button>    </form>
  </div>

  <script>
  function verificate_email() {
      const email = document.getElementById('email').value;

      // Ensure the email is valid
      var emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
      if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
          alert('Invalid email format');
          return false; // Prevent form submission
      }
      return true; // Allow form submission
  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>

and i get this error "Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError at /authentication/reset_password/
Exception Value: 'email'"
the problem is the code keep using GET methode even when i chose POST methode in the HTML page i chek the urls.py and the html file for "csrf_token" then i debug my code and i fund that the function using GET methode even if i set the methode to POST in the HTML file
